# Problemas com file_get_contents e DOMDocument

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-domdocument

Estou tentando baixar o conteúdo de uma site, porém está dando este warning:

> `DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : tr in Entity

E está indicando diversas linhas. também não estou conseguindo arrumar a acentuação.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender e solucionar estes problemas?

```php
$content = http_build_query([
    'Local' => 'Adamantina',
    'Inicio' => '01/01/2015',
    'Final' => '31/12/2015',
]);

$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $content,
    ]
]);

$contents = utf8_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.ciiagro.sp.gov.br/ciiagroonline/Listagens/BH/LBalancoHidricoLocal.asp', false, $context));

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($contents);
$dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$rows = $xpath->query('//table/tr[position()>0]');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $tds=$row->getElementsByTagName("td");   

    foreach ($tds as $td) {
        print($td->nodeValue);
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: assim:  `$rows = $xpath->query('//table');
$rows2 = $xpath->query('.//tr', $rows);

foreach($rows2 as $row){
 $tds=$row->getElementsByTagName("td"); 
 foreach($tds as $td){
  print ($td->nodeValue);
  echo "<br>";
 }
}`  não funcionou

Comment: É, este não é o problema, veja se a resposta ajuda a questão.

Answer (score 1):

**Problema de Warning:**

Para corrigir o problema do Warning você deve utilizar o `libxml_use_internal_errors()`, na verdade ele irá apenas ocultar os erros do `libxml`.

> Utilize o seguinte:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Fonte:  http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php

**Problema de acento:**

Para corrigir o problema de codificação utilize o `mb_convert_encoding()`, isto irá converter para HTML, mas *remova* o `utf8_decode()` anterior!

> Utilize o seguinte:

```
mb_convert_encoding($td->nodeValue, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

> Altere para algo similar à isto:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.ciiagro.sp.gov.br/ciiagroonline/Listagens/BH/LBalancoHidricoLocal.asp', false, $context);
```

Removendo o `utf8_decode()`.

**Nota:**

1. A maneira mais fácil para saber quando usar o HTML-ENTITIES, para mim, é saber que apresenta o `?` ao invés de `<?>` (com fundo preto) ou algumas combinações de caracteres "aleatórios". Lógico, isto é apenas para mim, que vou chutando até funcionar.
2. Acredito que seja melhor usar `cURL` ao invés de `file_get_contents()`,

Estou sem tempo, desculpe, irei tentar melhorar a resposta em breve.

Comment: Descobri que o site que estou tentando pegar os dados tem problemas no desenvolvimento, então deve ser o problema dele. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.